# UK standard visitor visa delay

Tags: visas, uk

I applied for a UK standard visiting visa on 19th March, 2019. My biometrics were done on the same date. To this date, the visa still hasn't arrived. It has been more than 15 working days and I didn't get any email updates.

Today I called UKVI and asked them about the status of my application. They said that the visa was already decided on the 2nd April, 2019. As I have still not received my visa (today is 11th April, 2019), what are my options?

Comment: I’m not sure if this will affect the answer, however where did you apply from?

Comment: Dublin, Ireland via TLS contact

Comment: It would be wise to give them a call and tell them the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend giving the British Embassy in Ireland a call on their telephone number:

> Tel.: +44 (0)20 7235 2171

You should explain the situation and they can provide you with more insight as to what is happening.